# postgres to query count when json value is match LIKE condition

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have mssql query which works to query the json data which kept in database column like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM t1.test where lower(data) LIKE '%state':'new%'
```

```
{
  "id": "DO-Test CC1",
  "state": "NEW",
  "type": "Test type",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemReports": [],
      "id": "066c7499-a4b6-4346-ac98-6a71d0ddfc36",
      "itemId": "Augmentn New",
      "quantity": 100,
      "dispenseAsWritten": false,
      "administrationInstructions": "123"
    }
  ]
}
```

It does not work when i run it at pgAdmin (postgres database).

i am using Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf5

which syntax should be replaced?

Comment: `'%state':'new%'` that won't work because (a) json elements won't be single quoted, and (b) you've got 2 strings there separate by a colon which is not part of those strings, so I'd expect pg to raise an exception. You're looking for `'%"state":"new"%'`, but of course you really should be using the json operator as in the answers below.

Comment: '%"state":"new"%' returned count 0

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `like` or anything similar. You can use `->>` to access the value of a key. If you don't know if it's upper or lower case, you can apply a lower() on the result of that expression:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
FROM t1.test 
where lower(data ->> 'state') = 'new';
```

---

If the column is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be) and you have a GIN index on the `data` column and you are sure that the state is always upper case, the following is probably more efficient:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
FROM t1.test 
where data @> '{"state": "NEW"}'
```

---

Update as you don't store your JSON in a `jsonb` column (which you should do), you need to cast the column to `jsonb` in order to be able to use the functions, e.g.

```
where lower(data::jsonb ->> 'state') = 'new';
```

or

```
where data::jsonb @> '{"state": "NEW"}
```

But you should really consider to change that column to `jsonb` rather than `varchar`

Comment: i am using Docker postgres version 19.03.4, build 9013bf5

Comment: There is no Postgres version 19.03, the current version is 12 - what do you get when you run `select version()`

Comment: @user12158726: see my edit how to do this with a `varchar` column (yes, that's the "data type")

Comment: 19.03 is returned when i try to get docker postgres version. i have no idea how to check exact postgres version by using docker command.

Comment: As I wrote: `select version();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `->>` JSON operator to access `state`'s value as `text`.

```
SELECT ...
       FROM ...
       WHERE data->>'state' = 'NEW';
```

Comment: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: text ->> unknown
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 55

Comment: @user12158726: It seems like you use the wrong datatype for the column `data` then. It should be `json` or `jsonb` but you seem to use `text` or `varchar`.

Comment: yup, now i understand why json or jsonb query does not works at all. my database datatype is varchar. in this case i cannot use json query.

Comment: @user12158726: Well, you could change the data type properly... Would be a waste if you lose all the possibilities to work with JSON Postgres offers.

Comment: not going to change data type as that violate the original arch design, will still seeking query for it, not using json query,